# signin vs. sign-in naming convention

Tags: css

I've been reading the google naming convention https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml

I've gotten the most down. However I still feel itchy when it comes to certain naming of things which include two or more words. A prime example is the following; *sign in*.

JavaScript:

```
var signIn; // this feels natural
```

CSS:

```
.sign-in-container { ... } // for me this feels unnatural
.signin-container { ... } // feels more natural for some reason
.signIn-container { ... } // goes against css naming
```

It's unnatrual because most of my css classes a hyphen seperates heierchary or function.

I was reading about the actual word *sign in* and it says *signin* can be mistaken for *signing* in some cases.

Is it *worth* putting a hypen between `sign` and `in`. I'm most likely overthinking this, but as a programmer, *sometimes small things really get to me*.

Would this effect SEO for example? Is there *any reason at all* to prefer or not prefer putting a hyphen between them?

Comment: FWIW, bootstrap uses hyphen for multi-word classes in CSS (all lowercase) - Your JS example seems correct to me as well

Comment: Why not just have a more generic container for things that need to be wrapped, and inside of it a reusable module named "sign-in"?

Comment: @ochi Thank you! I've yet to see any examples, I'll def check bootstrap now.

Answer (score 2):

Best go with what is recommended in the language you are writing in. In JavaScript you should stick to `camelCase`, however this is rarely used in CSS. Besides, this way one can't make use of the [|= attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#attribute-selectors).

That leaves us the last problem: should one use a dash in order to improve meaning of a variable, or should one avoid it in order to be consistent with similar variables?

```
.cart-container {} // prefix `cart` specializes the container class 
.blog-container {} // just like `blog`
.sign-in-container {} // however, this one isn't consistent this way
```

I prefer avoiding it, but it might be a personal preference.

> I'm most likely overthinking this, but as a programmer, sometimes
>   small things really get to me.

That's a common mistake programmers make I guess. The key is to fence of this in order to improve your productivity!

---

Although I highly discourage over thinking this, like you said. There are a couple of ways solving this problem:

**Choose a different name**

Like `.login-container`, which basically means the same.

**Create a more generic selector**

Like `.main-container`, `.content-container` or maybe even `.responsive-container` if it needs to be responsive.

Comment: Switching it to `.login` seems best... Also agreed on the reasoning for consistancy. I personally stick with camelCase, even in CSS; doing `[class|="foo"]` could very easily be done as `.foo` with your `.foo-bar` as `.foo.bar` (two classes, more semantically correct, faster parse/apply) instead... bonus it removes the required ordering `[attr|=val]` imposes. I also use dashes/underscores as pseudo-"namespaces". One example being a rather complex app where I've prefixed many js hook classes with either `data-` or `auto-` depending on what they do (such as `auto-dateNow` and `data-money`).

Comment: Not to spam, but I"m a derp, the ordering requirement would be on `[ ^= ]` not `[ |= ]`. Regardless, it's still significantly more semantically correct to split that into two classes, not having it exist as one block.

Comment: @abluejelly I agree with you that having multiple classes selectors results in quite a few benefits. But you would really have to know what you're doing, because it easily gets complex doing it the wrong way. Besides, it is not really friendly to those who want to extend the sheet, basically they will need to know everything about the structure of the CSS.

Comment: and having to worry about a reserved prefix requires less understanding of the "structure" of the CSS?

Comment: @abluejelly Actually yes, you do not have to worry about other frameworks reusing that class name for instance. That does apply to the CSS framework itself too, you basically only need to worry if the prefix is taken. While in your suggestion, you can't simply edit properties of a class without knowing the effect on every other dependent.